# Chrome extension asynchronus issue

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, messaging, google-chrome-app

I have the following code for my extension : 
**popup.js**

```
var p,textNode,a;
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({method: "getSett"}, function(response) {
  if(response === "1") {
    div=document.getElementById('content');
    p= document.createElement('p');
    textNode=document.createTextNode('The extension is paused');
    p.appendChild(textNode);
    div.appendChild(p);
    a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href ="#";
    a.setAttribute('id','pause');
    a.innerHTML="unpause";
    div.appendChild(a);
  }
  else {
    div=document.getElementById('content');
    p= document.createElement('p');
    textNode=document.createTextNode('The extension is running');
    p.appendChild(textNode);
    div.appendChild(p);
    a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = "#";
    a.setAttribute('id','pause');
    a.innerHTML = "pause";
    div.appendChild(a);
  }
});

var link=document.getElementById('pause');

link.onclick=function() { //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({method: "change"}, function(response){

    });
}
```

**background.js**

```
    function changeIcon(){
    if (localStorage['isPaused']=='1') {
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:{'19': "icons/icon_19_grayscale.png", '38': "icons/icon_19_grayscale.png"}});
    }
    else{
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:{'19': "icons/icon_19.png", '38': "icons/icon_19.png"}});
    }
}
function optionsSet(){
localStorage['isPaused']="0";
}
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (message.type === 'getSett') {
        var result = localStorage.getItem(isPaused.value);
        sendResponse(result);
    }
    else if(message.type === 'change') {
        var result = localStorage.getItem(isPaused.value)
        if(result==="1") {
            changeIcon();
            localStorage['isPaused']="0";
        }
        else {
            changeIcon();
            localStorage['isPaused']="1";
        }
        sendResponse('changed');
    }
    else if(message.type === 'resume') {
        localStorage['isPaused']="0";
        var response = "0";
        changeIcon();
        sendResponse(response);
    }
}
optionsSet();
```

What I'm trying to do is some kind of pause state(like in adblock) for my extension and I can't seem to put isPaused in localStorage .And I get an error in the popup.js where the comment is.
I can't understand why I get the error because the  element has the id set to pause.
Can someone please help me sort this out?

Thank you!

-Danny-

**EDIT**
I've replaced `chrome.storage.local.set` with `localStorage['isPaused']="0";` but I still can't get it to save it in localStorage.
I have no idea how to solve the async problem..Could someone suggest something? Would a setTimeout({},1000) work?( I have an async problem in getting the `<a>` element id at the end of popup.js)

Answer (score 2):

You have several errors. Among them:
1) localStorage != chrome.storage. read the docs.
2) chrome.storage is async and you are not coding for that when you set.
Both errors are grave. Fix them and try again.

Comment: You are now asking a different question. That's not how s.o. works.

Comment: Accept Zig's answer to your original question, then ask a new one.